# Mocha Tests with Webpack Feature Flags

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, webpack

we've been using webpack for a while now and recently started using feature flags:

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({ __DEV__: true })
],
```

We are using mocha for our unit tests:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-register --check-leaks --throw-deprecation --recursive Source/test",
    "test:watch": "npm test -- --watch"
},
```

The Problem is that mocha cannot handle them and I have found no way of faking them:

```
ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined
```

Is there any way to make this work?

Any way to tell mocha to inject the flags the same way webpack does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the webpack flags exist during compile time.
So there is no way to change them during run time.

The only options is to compile with different settings.